# EditText setText not displaying on a Dialog Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I'm kinda new to Android app development, and don't know how to debug this. So I'm trying to do EditText.setText on a DialogFragment. It prints out the right string on the log, but still showing the old string based on .xml file("Enter item here."). Is there any way to update it?

```
public class MyAlertDialogFragment extends DialogFragment{
public MyAlertDialogFragment() {}

public static MyAlertDialogFragment newInstance(String desc) {
    MyAlertDialogFragment frag = new MyAlertDialogFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("desc", desc);
    frag.setArguments(args);
    return frag;
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    alertDialogBuilder.setView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Edit to-do list");

    final View layout = View.inflate(MainActivity.getAppContext(), R.layout.custom_dialog, null);
    final EditText mEditText = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.EditDesc);
    String desc = getArguments().getString("desc");
    mEditText.setText(desc);
    System.out.println("EditText is " + mEditText.getText().toString());

    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK",  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // on success
            EditTodoFragment.EditTodoFragmentListener listener = (EditTodoFragment.EditTodoFragmentListener)getActivity();
            listener.onFinishEditDialog(mEditText.getText().toString());
        }
    });
    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    return alertDialogBuilder.create();
}
```

}

The log file

```
07-06 21:04:20.738 4115-4115/com.example.light.todolist I/System.out: EditText is Doing grocery
```

The xml file is:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="238dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Edit Item Below:"
    android:id="@+id/EditTitle"
    android:layout_weight="0.04" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/EditDesc"
    android:text="Enter item here.">
<requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't use layout view for Dialog so that you can't see text on EditText. Please change as here:

```
 AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Edit to-do list");

    final View layout = View.inflate(MainActivity.getAppContext(), R.layout.custom_dialog, null);
    alertDialogBuilder.setView(layout );
```

Comment: You're right! I have to use layout to setView, otherwise, it won't recognize it?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
View customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null);

alertDialogBuilder.setView(customView);
alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Edit to-do list");

final EditText mEditText = (EditText) customView.findViewById(R.id.EditDesc);
String desc = getArguments().getString("desc");
mEditText.setText(desc);

alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK",  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // on success
        EditTodoFragment.EditTodoFragmentListener listener = (EditTodoFragment.EditTodoFragmentListener)getActivity();
        listener.onFinishEditDialog(mEditText.getText().toString());
    }
});
alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});

return alertDialogBuilder.create();
```